# How to recursively list all hidden files and directories?

Tags: files, directory

I want to list all hidden files and directories and then save result to file.

Is there any command for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If using GNU find, you can do

```
find /path -path '*/.*' -ls | tee output-file
```

**Edit**

To avoid to show non-hidden items contained in hidden directories

```
find /path -name '.*' >output-file
```

(as noted, `tee` could be avoided if you do not need to see the output, and `-ls` option should be used only if required).

Comment: This also lists the contents of hidden directories, which isn't what the question asks for (probably — it is a little ambiguous).

Comment: @Gilles: indeed it is ambiguous. Edited the answer

Comment: Note that the first one is not GNU-specific. `-path` is POSIX since 2008. `-ls` is not standard but quite common.

Answer (score 13):

To list the hidden files and directories in the current directory, including `.` and `..`:

```
echo .*
```

To list the hidden files and directories in the current directory and its subdirectories recursively:

```
find . -name '.*'
```

If you want to save the results to a file, use a redirection:

```
find . -name '.*' >output-file.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` (using the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `D`):

```
print -rl ./**/.*(D)
```

To include non-hidden files in hidden directories:

```
setopt extendedglob
print -rl ./**/*~^*/.*(D)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually put the same argument multiple times in the same command line:

`find /storage/????-????/ -iname '.*' -iname "*" | tee -a file-list-micSD-20190801163729.fli`

The *`tee -a`* command is able to display the command's output (or *stdout*) simultaneously whie writing it to a file. The `-a` options prevents [clobbering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/clobbering) and does append the information to the target output file instead.

`/storage/????-????/` is an example path. It is the path to the MicroSD card of newer Android Mobile phones (there is also a terminal application for Android, with fewer commands but still many and significantly increased since Android 6.0). The MicroSD card was formerly `/storage/extSdCard`. Now, it is the volume serial number.